# Unable to install Jenkins suggested plugins when running through Docker on Mac M1

Tags: macos, jenkins, networking, docker-compose

I am using the following docker-compose.yml to start Jenkins on my Mac M1

```
version: '2'

networks:
  devnet:
    driver: bridge

services:
 nexus:
  image: sonatype/nexus
  container_name: nexus
  ports:
    - "8081:8081"
  networks:
    - devnet
  volumes:
    - "$PWD/opt/nexus/:/var/lib/nexus"

 jenkins:
  image: jenkins/jenkins:lts
  container_name: jenkins
  ports:
    - "8080:8080"
  networks:
    - devnet
  volumes:
    - "$PWD/jenkins:/var/jenkins_home"

 sonarqube:
  image: sonarqube
  container_name: sonarqube
  restart: always
  ports:
   - "9000:9000"
  networks:
    - devnet
  depends_on:
    - sonardb
  links:
    - sonardb
  environment:
   - SONARQUBE_JDBC_URL=jdbc:postgresql://sonardb:5432/sonar
   - SONARQUBE_JDBC_USERNAME=sonar
   - SONARQUBE_JDBC_PASSWORD=sonar
  volumes:
    - "$PWD/opt/sonar/:/var/lib/sonar"

 sonardb:
  networks:
    - devnet
  image: postgres:9.6.1
  container_name: postgres
  restart: always
  environment:
   - POSTGRES_USER=sonar
   - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=sonar
   - POSTGRESQL_DB=sonar
  ports:
    - "5432:5432"
  volumes:
    - "$PWD/opt/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql"
```

When I continue installation via $open http://127.0.0.1:8080 and select the  “Install suggested plugins” they all fail to install.

[image]
Compared to when I do it natively on my Mac via "brew install jenkins-lts". it works.

I tried searching for a similar issue on Jenkins forums or Stack Overflow, but could not find answer. A few people posted similar problem.

Adding Log:

```
2024-03-25 11:51:01.878+0000 [id=82]    SEVERE  h.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob#run: Failed to install ionicons-api
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
Caused: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed
        at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
Caused: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
.....
Caused: java.io.IOException: Failed to load https://updates.jenkins.io/download/plugins/ionicons-api/56.v1b_1c8c49374e/ionicons-api.hpi to /var/jenkins_home/plugins/ionicons-api.jpi.tmp
        at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$UpdateCenterConfiguration.download(UpdateCenter.java:1334)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Failed to download from https://updates.jenkins.io/download/plugins/ionicons-api/56.v1b_1c8c49374e/ionicons-api.hpi (redirected to: https://ftp-chi.osuosl.org/pub/jenkins/plugins/ionicons-api/56.v1b_1c8c49374e/ionicons-api.hpi)
....
Caused: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed
        at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
Caused: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Comment: If you know how to access logs they might provide some clues.

Comment: @Iterokun I have added logs: They indicate SSL Certificate issue: PKIX path building failed. Can I please get the -1 removed?

Comment: To see what kind of cert you are getting run `docker exec jenkins openssl s_client -showcerts ftp-chi.osuosl.org:443`. In some corp environments you might be behind a proxy that decrypts and encrypts all the http traffic. The corp cert is usually pushed to the emplyee's machines, but not to the VMs running on those machines. Just a theory.